# how to get key/value from xpath string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, string

I'm working on ruby on rails project and I have a string

```
cmd = "\"//div/table/tbody/tr/td/label[text()=\"Select Year\"]/preceding-sibling::*[1]\" = \"2014\""
```

I want to get key/value like this:

```
key:   "//div/table/tbody/tr/td/label[text()=\"Select Year\"]/preceding-sibling::*[1]"
value: "2014"
```

The key is a xpath. I was using cmd.split("=") which is not correct. I think i can use regex to parse the string but don't know how. Please advice.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The string you have given, is invalid!

Comment: Sorry, i have updated the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using split will work for you .

```
2.1.1 :006 > cmd = '"//div/table/tbody/tr/td/label[text()=\"Select Year\"]/preceding-sibling::*[1]" = "2014"'
 => "\"//div/table/tbody/tr/td/label[text()=\\\"Select Year\\\"]/preceding-sibling::*[1]\" = \"2014\"" 
2.1.1 :007 > cmd.split(" = ")[0]
 => "\"//div/table/tbody/tr/td/label[text()=\\\"Select Year\\\"]/preceding-sibling::*[1]\"" 
2.1.1 :008 > cmd.split(" = ")[1]
 => "\"2014\""
```

save the first as key and the second as value.

Comment: No, there may have many "=" in the string. So you will get not expected key value. the split may return several elements

Comment: @Morris that is why i splitted on `\s=\s`

Answer (score 0):

Now, i got solution. See below:
my original string:

```
a = "\"//div/table/tbody/tr/td/label[text()=\\\"Select Year\\\"]/preceding-sibling::*[1]\" = \"2014\""
```

I'm using:

```
a.match('[\w\W]*\"[\s]*=')[0]
```

to get string:

```
"\"//div/table/tbody/tr/td/label[text()=\\\"Select Year\\\"]/preceding-sibling::*[1]\" ="
```

Then i can use substring to get the rest string.